# Download Export in Matter by C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download an export in matter from my google workspace.
This give me this error:

> Google.GoogleApiException: 'The service storage has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. No error message was specified.'
> JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Detail of My Matter Export Bucket

```
            {
                "bucketName": "94b1f695-67fb-4221-bf5f-9914d7fb667a",
                "md5Hash": "b54f5159da45e3cc2071039cbe7acb15",
                "objectName": "dc7e579e-32da-4f8b-9646-30fcf188255f/exportly-a7ac724a-f622-415f-b0df-1547d020ded6/Export5-1.zip",
                "size": 13069107,
                "ETag": null
            },
```

```
            GoogleCredential GoogleCredentials = MGoogleCredentials.GetGoogleCredential(); // This take from my Accont Service json and it works fine
            StorageClient StorageClient = StorageClient.Create(GoogleCredentials);
            string BucketName = "94b1f695-67fb-4221-bf5f-9914d7fb667a";
            string ObjectName = "dc7e579e-32da-4f8b-9646-30fcf188255f/exportly-a7ac724a-f622-415f-b0df-1547d020ded6/Export5-1.zip";
            // string ObjectName = "Export5-1";

            using (MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                StorageClient.DownloadObject(BucketName, ObjectName, Stream);

            }
```

Comment: But what's your problem? We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: I have an Export in a Matter in Google Vault.
I need to download this file content in the Export by Code.
The code in the google api is this I put avobe by give me the error I descrived
I'm using c# in Visual Studio 2019

Thanks in advance

Comment: `HttpStatusCode is Forbidden` this is usually because the credentials you're using do not have permission for the requested resource.